# implementation error - picasso:2.71828 (More than one file was found with OS independent path)

Tags: android, gradle, picasso, okhttp

An error occurred when I wrote this syntax to add the picasso library.

(More than one file was found with OS independent path 'okhttp3/internal/publicsuffix/publicsuffixes.gz')

My android gradle is as follows!!

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.i203_153.smarthome"
    minSdkVersion 24
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation files('libs/jackson-annotations-2.1.2.jar')
    implementation files('libs/com.fasterxml.jackson.core.jar')
    implementation files('libs/com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.jar')
}
```

How do I fix the following errors? Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
```

Comment: thanks to your comment! I tried it, but when using picasso 2.5.0, the following warnning occurred.
[Setting airplane_mode_on has moved from android.provider.Settings.System to android.provider.Settings.Global, returning read-only value.] how can I do??

Comment: Picasso.with(getContext()).load(img_path).into(profile); its work properly in my project